# ROLLBACK doesn't work after INSERT INTO newly created destination table

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction, rollback

I am working on PHP-script which imports CSV file (`customers.csv`) into MySQL table (`customers`).

Before inserting contents of CSV-file into the mysql table I am first backing up the original `customers` table.

I am wrapping whole import process (including backing up) in a mysql transaction (to account for cases when CSV is corrupt somewhere in the middle, and to ensure import is atomic).

The problem is that **ROLLBACK doesn't seem to work when I am calling it right after `INSERT INTO` statement: when checking database via phpMyAdmin I can see the newly created table AND ROWS INSIDE IT still present after roollback**.

Here's the log of the operations:

```
[2015-01-19 14:08:11] DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2015-01-19 14:08:11] DEBUG: SHOW TABLES LIKE :table_name; [] []
[2015-01-19 14:08:28] DEBUG: CREATE TABLE `customers__20150119_14_08_20` LIKE `customers` [] []
[2015-01-19 14:08:37] DEBUG: INSERT INTO `customers__20150119_14_08_20` SELECT * FROM `customers` [] []
[2015-01-19 14:08:50] DEBUG: "ROLLBACK" [] []
```

So I wonder why depsite `ROLLBACK` is called, the transaction is not cancelled. I do understand that `CREATE TABLE` is not transactional in nature and can't be rolled back. But I was assuming that `INSERT INTO` because it deals with inserting rows (not defining schema), WILL actually be transactional, and after ROLLBACK I will be left with empty destination table. Why is it not the case?

And here's output `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers` (so my table is `InnoDb`):

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
 `Code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Price` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Code`),
 KEY `Price` (`Price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and here's output for the desination table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers__20150119_14_08_20` (
 `Code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Price` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Code`),
 KEY `Price` (`Price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if you reorder to first `create table`, then `start transaction, insert, rollback`?

Comment: I was just about to say that to !!!

Comment: Do you disable autocommit on the connection in your program?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that that some statements, like `CREATE TABLE` cause an implicit commit. You can read about them in the documentation: [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html).

So the original sequence of statements:

```
START TRANSACTION
SHOW TABLES LIKE customers
CREATE TABLE `customers__20150119_14_08_20` LIKE `customers`
INSERT INTO `customers__20150119_14_08_20` SELECT * FROM `customers`
ROLLBACK
```

will expand into:

```
START TRANSACTION ;   -- transaction context created
SHOW TABLES LIKE customers ;

COMMIT ;              -- CREATE TABLE forces commit before itself
                      --     (at this point the previous transaction is done.)
START TRANSACTION ;   -- and a new transaction  
CREATE TABLE `customers__20150119_14_08_20` 
    LIKE `customers` ;
COMMIT ;              -- CREATE TABLE forces commit after itself. 
                      -- At this point there's no transaction context

START TRANSACTION ;   --  starts a new transaction
INSERT INTO `customers__20150119_14_08_20` 
    SELECT * FROM `customers` ;
COMMIT ;              -- caused by "autocommit on" setting (guess). 

ROLLBACK ;            -- this rollback HAS NOTHING to undo
```

The solution would be to start the transaction (or a new one) after the `CREATE TABLE` statement or use a temporary table.

Comment: @Dimitry, thnx for the edit.

Comment: And @RolandoMySQLDBA for your kind words. I am the FGITW today (and only 15 seconds faster than you ;)

Comment: @ypercube welcome! It took me a while to figure where exactly this CREAT TABLE will `cause an implicit commit`... So had to do this outline on paper anyways :) @RolandoMySQLDBA thank for rapid input as well. I have read few dozens of your replies in the last year and they helped me a lot!!

Comment: So you're saying that the implicit commit _before_ the `INSERT`, caused by the DDL statement, also somehow causes a commit _after_ the insert?

Comment: @mustaccio No, I'm saying that *["By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit mode enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html)* That's what my "autocommit (guess)" refers to. I'm guessing he had autocommit on. The explicit transaction he had started had been commited by the `CREATE TABLE` but the INSERT transaction was auto-committed.

Comment: But your answer starts with _some statements... cause an implicit commit_, and the suggestion is to move around the `CREATE TABLE` statement...

Comment: In other words, if the problem is in the autocommit setting, it should not matter if you start the transaction after the `CREATE` implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Yes, there are two parts on the reasoning but the main part in my opinion, that the OP could not figure out was the implicit commit by the create table.

Comment: If you start with autocommit off on the other hand, you'll have to always commit or rollback the transaction. I'm not sure why you are suggesting that. I suggest explicitly starting and committing the transactions.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, just trying to understand what the answer is.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the order of the statements is causing the problem.

In my old post [row locking within ACID transaction innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712), I named 12 statements that break a transaction intermittently. In your particular case, it was the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Once you ran `CREATE TABLE` inside a `START TRANSACTION` ... `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` block, there was no framework to rollback.

Just run the `CREATE TABLE` before `START TRANSACTION` and you should be fine.

Give it a Try !!!