# Transaction has set autocommit = 0, but still the update happens before I commit

Tags: mysql, transaction, ddl

I have multiple MySQL InnoDb tables, I am trying to alter/insert/modify many of them in a SQL transaction, I set `autocommit` to false, so that if some SQL statements fail, I do commit the rest of statements:

```
set autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
use database1;
update `table1` set tkey = '3' .....;
update `table1` set tkey = '4' .......;
update `table1` set tkey = '5' .......;
update `table1` set tkey = '6' .......;
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD COLUMN `.....` bool NOT NULL; -- This fails
COMMIT;
```

In above transaction the `alter` against table2 fails, but still the updates to table 1 have happened, how can I avoid that? I want a rollback even if one statement fails.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL most DDL statements, including `ALTER TABLE`, implicitly issue a `COMMIT` before executing. It's [described in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html).

One way to do what you want is reorder your statements, placing `update`s after the `alter`.

Comment: This applies also to other DBMS

Comment: @frlan -- this applies to _some_ other DBMSes.

Comment: What if the sql has insert/delete/update/alter statements all in one?

Comment: @user60611 -- I'm afraid I don't understand the question. How can you have multiple statements "all in one"?

Answer (score 0):

Certain statements trigger an implicit commit. `ALTER TABLE` is definitely one of them.

See my post [row locking within ACID transaction innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712) on all statements that do this.

With regard to your transaction, any of the updates that fail will rollback previous updates. You need to create a flag that checks whether or not the transaction went to completion. You need to setup Dynamic SQL to pull that off. Perhaps something like this:

```
SET @OK_TO_ALTER = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
use database1;
update `table1` set tkey = '3' .....;
update `table1` set tkey = '4' .......;
update `table1` set tkey = '5' .......;
update `table1` set tkey = '6' .......;
SET @OK_TO_ALTER = 1;
COMMIT;
SET @sql = 'SELECT 1 DoNothing';
SET @sql = IF(@OK_TO_ALTER=1,'ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD COLUMN `.....` bool NOT NULL',@sql);
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

BTW you do not need `set autocommit = 0;` for a `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` block.

Comment: Looks like it will work in this case, but I have a sql script which has many such statements, with insert/update/delete sql statements in it, 
The above approach will add a lot of IF conditions.
are there any other ways to make it ACID?

Comment: Please look over my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712. Any of your transactions with those statements must have those statement placed somewhere else in your code.